# How to create a basemap by combining maps in PDF format

Tags: pdf, basemap

I have thousands of digital map files with 2500 scale and in pdf format. All of them have their sheet numbers. I have a (.shp) grid file for the alignment of these sheets. I aim to make a basemap by combining all these digital maps. Is there a road map to do this? Will I need to use AutoCAD? I attached a screenshot of a pdf file below

[image: digital map]

Comment: Do you individual pdfs for each parcel or for each grid section?  Do these have individual vector layers or are they raster?  Are they georeferenced or is that something you will have to do for each.  What software do you have besides AutoCAD?  If you added a pdf to QGIS and it had vector layers and georeferenced you might get vector data you could merge.   But if at best you get parcel rasters maps, then collars/margins, legends, other data, etc, will overlap all the maps under it even if the pdfs are georeferenced.